# How to properly prevent Data loss for analytics data?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization

I am currently writing an analytics system.
Currently, it caches Events in RAM.
It writes to the Filesystem via NSUserDefaults (iOS) and SharedPreferences (Android) when the App closes, as JSON.
This Data is read when the app opens.

It also sends every N seconds or when the amount of Events reaches 20.
When the sending was successful, it deletes all events that were send from the RAM.

This has some obvious flaws: When the app crashes, all data from N seconds is lost. When the server cannot be reached (because Server is down for example) and the app crashes, even more data are lost.

My question here is: How can I improve the "safety" of my data and prevent massive data loss when the server is down or not reachable?

Here is my current code (unimportant parts removed)

```
import Foundation
class BackendTrackingHandler : TrackingHandler {
    static let KEY_CACHE_EVENT = "TrackingCache"
    private static let SEND_INTERVAL:TimeInterval = 10
    var cachedEvents: [TrackingEvent] = []
    var temporaryCachedEvents: [TrackingEvent] = []
    var prefix: String
    var endpoint: String
    var timer : Timer?
    //whether we currently wait for a response
    var isSending: Bool = false

override init() {
    //init
    readCachedEventsFromDisk()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: BackendTrackingHandler.SEND_INTERVAL, target: self, selector: #selector(send), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

    override func trackEvent(_ event: TrackingEvent) {
        cachedEvents.append(event)
        if((cachedEvents.count) >= 20) {
            send()
        }
    }

    @objc func send() {

        if((cachedEvents.count) < 1) {
            return
        }
        if(isSending) {
            return
        }
        isSending = true
        let enc = JSONEncoder()
        enc.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        let data = try! enc.encode(cachedEvents)
        // Constructring Request here
        let session = URLSession.shared
        //while the request is on the way, we can trigger new events. Make a temporary copy
        temporaryCachedEvents = cachedEvents
        let taksID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask()
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if(error != nil)
            {
                self.isSending = false
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taksID)
            }else {
                let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                if(httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode <= 299) {
                    //success, Data was sent so we can create a new cached event
                    //remove all events we already sent
                    self.cachedEvents = self.cachedEvents.filter{!self.temporaryCachedEvents.contains($0)}
                    self.isSending = false
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taksID)

                }else {
                    self.isSending = false
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taksID)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    func readCachedEventsFromDisk() {
        let dec = JSONDecoder()
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: BackendTrackingHandler.KEY_CACHE_EVENT) else {
            cachedEvents = []
            return
        }
        do {

            cachedEvents = try dec.decode([TrackingEvent].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            cachedEvents = []
        }
    }

    func writeCachedEventsToDisk() {
        let enc = JSONEncoder()
        let data = try! enc.encode(cachedEvents)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: BackendTrackingHandler.KEY_CACHE_EVENT)
    }

    override func onApplicationBecomeActive() {
    }

    override func onApplicationBecomeInactive() {
        let taskID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask()
        writeCachedEventsToDisk()
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskID)
    }
}
```

€dit:
`TrackingEvent` is a struct that is shared among multiple `TrackingHandler`s. There is an additional `FirebaseTrackingHandler`, which is meant to be operated side-by-side our own analytics system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is writing "Property Wrapper" for `cachedEvents` so it would directly access to UserDefaults, it seems the operation is not so huge to bother.

Second way - you could simply save cache to UserDefaults every N seconds/minutes or so if you care about performance a lot. Though, it wouldn't made your system bulletproof

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about writing to the file system in intervals, too.
I now write every event to the file system immediately :)